# p5.js scripts within a flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, p5.js

I am trying to create a flexbox that contains some examples of p5.js projects. I was just wondering how I can call the functions within the flexbox division. Below is a sample of code where I have created a dropdown. Within this id like to feature some of the p5 examples. How might I do this?

```
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Projects</button>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Nam at lectus
        urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Massa tincidunt nunc
        pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
    <hr class="rounded">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Nam at lectus
        urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Massa tincidunt nunc
        pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
    <hr class="rounded">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Nam at lectus
        urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Massa tincidunt nunc
        pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
    <hr class="rounded">

        <div class="flex-container">
            <div>
                <script >
                  // p5.js script here
                </script>
            </div>

            <div>
              <script >
                 // p5.js script here
              </script>
          </div>

          <div>
            <script >
               **// p5.js script here**
            </script>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

[image]

**Id like it to look similar to this example above, but using scripts to create the objects**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create three empty `<div>` which will contain the `<canvas>` into which you'll render the p5.js sketches.

When you create a p5.js instance, you can specify its container providing a second argument to the constructor. Check the last two examples in https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instance-container.html

Anyway, you should be able to re-use the code below and adjust it to your case:

```js
// create three divs, pass in each one a pointer and attach them to a different .flex-item element

// p5 sketch 1
const sketch1 = function(p) {
  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(100, 100);
    p.background(0);
  }
};
const node1 = document.createElement('div');
new p5(sketch1, node1);
window.document.getElementById('p5-1').appendChild(node1);

// p5 sketch 2
const sketch2 = function(p) {
  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(100, 100);
    p.background(200);
  }
};
const node2 = document.createElement('div');
new p5(sketch2, node2);
window.document.getElementById('p5-2').appendChild(node2);

// p5 sketch 3
const sketch3 = function(p) {
  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(100, 100);
    p.background(128);
  }
};
const node3 = document.createElement('div');
new p5(sketch3, node3);
window.document.getElementById('p5-3').appendChild(node3);
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.flex-item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Projects</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Nam at lectus urna duis
    convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula
    ullamcorper malesuada. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
  <hr class="rounded">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Nam at lectus urna duis
    convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula
    ullamcorper malesuada. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
  <hr class="rounded">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Nam at lectus urna duis
    convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula
    ullamcorper malesuada. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
  <hr class="rounded">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="p5-1" class="flex-item"></div>
    <div id="p5-2" class="flex-item"></div>
    <div id="p5-3" class="flex-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep it mind that it's using `const` instead of `var` (an ES6 feature), so I would suggest to run it through a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) if you're concerned with cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I tried implementing this, but I cant seem to get it too work

Comment: @de19 I added a snippet, you should be able to adapt it to your case.